# Process started,no errors,activity not visible on Android >1.6

Tags: android, android-activity, visibility

I have developed an App that launches and works fine on Android 1.5 and 1.6.

When I try and use it on version higher then that the app's activity starts, progress dialogs popup and I can see my AsyncTask executing and the info being returned via Logcat. No errors or exceptions are shown.

But the Activity never displays. All I see is the progress dialog showing over the home screen and then nothing. The process is active and running under the DDMS view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Been looking into this for the whole morning and the activity works fine, gets all the data it's supposed to and resides in memory with no problems. 

It just will not display. I'm totally lost at what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had to explicity call setVisible(true) in my onCreate() method. Even though the root layout component of the activities had visibility="true" already.